# Vuex data store not found in components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm using a project with Vue, Vuetify, Vue-Router, and Vuex.  The intent was to create a basic layout with a sidebar in a more module approach to dabble in scalability with Vue.  So I created a folder called Store, which has a modules folder.  So my index file within the store folder is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import global from './Modules/Global';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
     modules: {
          site: global
     }
});
```

The module is broken down into a single file with actions, getters, mutations, and state.

```
const actions = {
    sidebarState: ({ commit }, status) => {
        commit('openOrCloseSidebar', status);
    }
}

const mutations = {
    openOrCloseMenu: (status) => {
        if (status !== true)
            return state.sidebar = true;

        return state.sidebar = false;
    }
};

const getters = {

};

const state = {
    sidebar: true
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters,
    state
};
```

I invoke the Vue instance as follows.

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Axios from 'axios';

import application from './Template/Application.vue';

import router from './Router';
import store from './Store';
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(router);
Vue.use(store);

sync(store, router);

var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#application',
    template: '<application></application>',
    components: {
        application
    },

    router: router,
    store: store
});
```

However, when I call `this.$store.global.state.sidebar` or `this.$store.state.sidebar` Vue is unable to find my property.  I receive the error:

> Cannot read property global of undefined.

The error also references state, but I believe since I'm using namespace the syntax should mirror above.  Where I attempt to call that is here.

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <application_sidebar :my-prop="menu"></application_sidebar>
        <application_navigation :my-prop="menu"></application_navigation>        
    </v-container>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    import application_navigation from './Navigation.vue'
    import application_sidebar from './Sidebar.vue';
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';

    export default ({
        components: {
            application_navigation,
            application_sidebar
        },

        data: {
            menu: this.$store.global.state.sidebar
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to access my state and learn how to correctly emit, so in the navigation component I can emit upward so the value is reflected to move the sidebar open or close.

Any help would be terrific, I'm quite new to Vue.

Comment: Afaik you need to pass the configuration to your store in your main.js. Also `Vue.use(Vuex);` should be in your main.js

Comment: @connexo Aren't I doing that with the `Vue.use(store)` that calls it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem is your path to your module state is meant to be `this.$store.state.site`.

The [recommended method](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components) is to use computed properties. For example

```
computed: {
  menu() {
    return this.$store.state.site.sidebar
  }
}
```

You can also use the [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: mapState({ menu: state => state.site.sidebar })
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the path to the state object. Your solution is definitely the best practice for setting computed properties that need to react to the vuex state. Which seems to be what OP is trying to do (not clear). But I think it's helpful in some cases to know you can initialize data properties with values from the store in the `data` method, so I'll leave my answer around too.

Comment: You've shed some light, I appreciate your answer.  I'm still having a similar issue but I believe I understand what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` variable does not reference the Vue instance when you are trying to access the store via `this.$store`.

The `data` object needs to be a method that returns an object.

```
data() {
  return { menu: this.$store.state.site.sidebar };
}
```

However, by retrieving the value from the store's `state` object the `data` method like this, you are only setting the value of the `menu` data property when the Vue instance initializes. The value of `menu` *will not update* in response to changes to the value in the store's `state`.

If you need the `menu` value to be reflective of the `state` object throughout the life of the Vue instance, then you'd need to use a computed property or `mapState`, as suggested in @Phil's answer.

Comment: I think you need to access `this.$store.state.site.sidebar`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, you've shed some light.